# Encoding text in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, razor

I have one .cshtml file in mvc c#
I want to encode string using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode but its resulting into namespace error.
Can anyone help me how i can encode this text "PICO+"?

```
<div id="pageTitleText">[@Model.Item.Key]
     @if (!Model.IsUserReadonly && !Model.ReadOnlyCachesList.Contains(Model.CacheName))
     {


         <span class="itemActions">
             <a class="edit" href="@Url.Content("~/caches")/@Model.CacheName/edit?key=@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("PICO+")">Edit</a>
             <a class="clone" href="@Url.Content("~/caches")/@Model.CacheName/clone?key=@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("PICO+")">Clone</a>
             <a id="evictItem" class="evict" href="#">Evict</a>
             <a id="deleteItem" class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
         </span>
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @Html.Encode, I've edited your code:

```
<div id="pageTitleText">[@Model.Item.Key]
     @if (!Model.IsUserReadonly && !Model.ReadOnlyCachesList.Contains(Model.CacheName))
     {


         <span class="itemActions">
             <a class="edit" href="@Url.Content("~/caches")/@Model.CacheName/edit?key=@Url.Encode("PICO+")">Edit</a>
             <a class="clone" href="@Url.Content("~/caches")/@Model.CacheName/clone?key=@Url.Encode("PICO+")">Clone</a>
             <a id="evictItem" class="evict" href="#">Evict</a>
             <a id="deleteItem" class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
         </span>
     }
</div>
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: getting below error
'Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.HtmlHelpers' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.HtmlHelpers' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my code to fit your requirements. You have to use Url.Encode

Comment: 'Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.UrlHelpers' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.UrlHelpers' could be found

Comment: I think you have problems with your web.config, when you type @Url.Encode visual studio shows you help text?

Comment: <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase,System.Web">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor"/>
       <add namespace="System.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
is it correct?